# Javascript create and reference cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm new to Javascript and am trying to figure out how to make use of cookies. I'm using a simple code I found on a click counter and would like to know how to go about using cookies to save the number of clicks from the user, and allow the user to continue from where they left off the next time the page is open.

Here is the code I am using:

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="onClick()">CLICK</button>
<p>You have clicked <a id="clicks">0</a> times!</p>
<script src="../scripts.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance! -Leo

Comment: Better use localstorage, not cookies. It's much easier as well.

Comment: I agree with @Bergi and @TheMonarch on using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), however for sake of actually answering your question, I suggest you look into [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) which is also available from [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/js-cookie) to easily import it into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use local storage instead.

Store: `localStorage.setItem('clicks', JSON.stringify(clicks))`

Retrieve: `var clicks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('clicks'))`